# Can pytest run tests within a test class?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a bunch of tests which I decided to put within a class, sample code is below:

```
class IntegrationTests:

    @pytest.mark.integrationtest
    @pytest.mark.asyncio
    async def test_job(self):
        assert await do_stuff()
```

However, when I try to run the tests:
`pipenv run pytest -v -m integrationtest`, they are not detected at all, where I got the following before moving them to a class:

```
5 passed, 4 deselected in 0.78 seconds
```

I now get this:

```
2 passed, 4 deselected in 0.51 seconds
```

Why does `pytest` not detect these tests? Are test classes not supported?

Comment: I added an answer to your question.

Comment: These are kind of the cases where running a test as a simple main can be of the same value as running circles around tailoring a framework with so much ceremony. PyTest is still nice of course.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The name of the class needs to start with `Test` for the pytest discovery to find it.

```
class TestIntegration:

    @pytest.mark.integrationtest
    @pytest.mark.asyncio
    async def test_job(self):
        assert await do_stuff()
```

See [Conventions for Python test discovery](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#test-discovery)

Comment: Ha, that's it, thanks. I tried all sorts of other stuff, even got the tests to run, but then fixtures did not want to work.

Answer (score 7):

### Create a pytest.ini

From [the docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/pythoncollection.html#changing-naming-convention):

> In case you need to change the naming convention for test files, classes and tests, you can create a file `pytest.ini`, and set the options `python_files`, `python_classes`, and `python_functions`:

### Example:

```
# content of pytest.ini
# Example 1: have pytest look for "check" instead of "test"
# can also be defined in tox.ini or setup.cfg file, although the section
# name in setup.cfg files should be "tool:pytest"
[pytest]
python_files = check_*.py
python_classes = *Tests
python_functions = *_check
```

In your case, if you don't want to change the name of the class `IntegrationTests`, set `python_classes` to `*Tests`.

#### Running tests inside a class

```
pytest /path/to/test_file_name.py::ClassName
```

#### Running a test inside a class

```
pytest /path/to/test_file_name.py::ClassName::test_name
```

Answer (score 1):

To run all the tests under the class, "TestIntegration" you can use:

```
pytest -k TestIntegration
```

Answer (score 0):

put the decorator above the class,  the class with tests inside is like a group already.

```
@pytest.mark.smoke1
class TestClass():
```